# XPATH Challenge - Want to Copy an Inner Element

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am struggling with what should be a simple XSL: Copy the updateResponse from the message below (note: I need XPATH 1.0 syntax for my integration system compatibility):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:n="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <updateResponse>
            <result>
                <id>001S000000J1Bu0IAF</id>
                <success>true</success>
            </result>
        </updateResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I simply want the result structure to be:

```
<updateResponse xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
    <result>
        <id>001S000000J1Bu0IAF</id>
        <success>true</success>
    </result>
</updateResponse>
```

I am able to copy the soap objects, but am unsuccessful in copying the children of the soapenv:Body element. The first copy-of works for Body, but the second does not resolve the XPATH. My XMLSPY tool xpath query editor says the xpath is valid, but the XSL does not resolve.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:urn="enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="soapenv" result-prefix="foo"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/urn:updateResponse"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/urn:updateResponse">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What expressions have you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your namespaces are mismatched between your data and your stylesheet, that seems to be the only problem.

In your stylesheet document, change this:

```
xmlns:urn="enterprise.soap.sforce.com"
```

to this:

```
xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com"
```

Then it will match the declared namespaces in your original input file.

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <xsl:template match="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body//*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}"
                     namespace="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<updateResponse xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
    <result>
        <id>001S000000J1Bu0IAF</id>
        <success>true</success>
    </result>
</updateResponse>
```

**Note**: First, the namespace declaration in your stylesheet is wrong. It should be `xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com"`. Second, for an exact result you need to strip in scope namespaces (there are three: `xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"`, `xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com"` (default), and `xmlns:n="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com`)

Answer (score 0):

The namespaces in this document are weird; you have xmlns and xmlns:n both assigned to the same namespace. It looks like `//soapenv:updateResponse` should work. Have you tried that?